# Filter out zeros in np.percentile

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, percentile

I am trying to decile the column `score` of a `DataFrame`.

I use the following code:

```
np.percentile(df['score'], np.arange(0, 100, 10))
```

My problem is in `score`, there are lots of zeros. How can I filter out these 0 values and only decile the rest of values?

Answer (score 3):

Filter them with boolean indexing:

```
df.loc[df['score']!=0, 'score']
```

or

```
df['score'][lambda x: x!=0]
```

and pass that to the percentile function.

```
np.percentile(df['score'][lambda x: x!=0], np.arange(0,100,10))
```

Comment: @MSeifert Since they added it recently I assumed it would be efficient but never actually tested it (I've been using it when I have long DataFrame names). Let me look around a little. :)

Comment: You're right. It operates on whole columns so it's performs as fast as masking.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply mask zeros and then remove them from your column using [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays):

```
score = df['score']
score_no_zero = score[score != 0]
np.percentile(score_no_zero, np.arange(0,100,10))
```

or in one step:

```
np.percentile(df['score'][df['score'] != 0], np.arange(0,100,10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(score=np.random.rand(20))
).where(
    np.random.choice([True, False], (20, 1), p=(.8, .2)),
    0
)

       score
0   0.380777
1   0.559356
2   0.103099
3   0.800843
4   0.262055
5   0.389330
6   0.477872
7   0.393937
8   0.189949
9   0.571908
10  0.133402
11  0.033404
12  0.650236
13  0.593495
14  0.000000
15  0.013058
16  0.334851
17  0.000000
18  0.999757
19  0.000000
```

Use `pd.qcut` to decile

```
pd.qcut(df.loc[df.score != 0, 'score'], 10, range(10))

0     4
1     6
2     1
3     9
4     3
5     4
6     6
7     5
8     2
9     7
10    1
11    0
12    8
13    8
15    0
16    3
18    9
Name: score, dtype: category
Categories (10, int64): [0 < 1 < 2 < 3 ... 6 < 7 < 8 < 9]
```

Or all together

```
df.assign(decile=pd.qcut(df.loc[df.score != 0, 'score'], 10, range(10)))

       score decile
0   0.380777    4.0
1   0.559356    6.0
2   0.103099    1.0
3   0.800843    9.0
4   0.262055    3.0
5   0.389330    4.0
6   0.477872    6.0
7   0.393937    5.0
8   0.189949    2.0
9   0.571908    7.0
10  0.133402    1.0
11  0.033404    0.0
12  0.650236    8.0
13  0.593495    8.0
14  0.000000    NaN
15  0.013058    0.0
16  0.334851    3.0
17  0.000000    NaN
18  0.999757    9.0
19  0.000000    NaN
```